# New Relic not logging custom parameters on transactions

Tags: asp.net, .net, monitoring, newrelic

I have a ASP.NET app that I'm trying to log custom parameters from to NewRelic. The code for logging looks like this:

```
this.searchResults = performanceMonitor.RecordQuery(() => searchManager.DoQuery(this.searchRequest));
```

The `performanceMonitor` is just an object that does this:

```
public TSearchResult RecordQuery<TSearchResult>(Func<TSearchResult> query) where TSearchResult : SearchResult
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = query();
    stopwatch.Stop();

    var externalTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var internalTime = ToMilliseconds(result.ExecutionTicks);

    NewRelicHelper.AddAttributeToTransaction("QueryExternalTime", externalTime);
    NewRelicHelper.AddAttributeToTransaction("QueryInternalTime", internalTime);

    return result;
}
```

All the line with `NewRelicHelper` does is call `NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.AddCustomParameter` with `"QueryExternalTime"` and `externalTime`.

Yet after executing this code on machines with NewRelic agents, when I run a NewRelic query, I cannot see either `QueryExternalTime` or `QueryInternalTime` with their respective values on any transactions.

Comment: Are you doing this on your production servers? As newrelic agents work on the assigned servers only .

Comment: This is no longer a problem. I was under the impression that the servers I was looking at had the NewRelic agent installed; they do not. Now I'm looking at the right servers, and the attributes show up as expected.